# Почему встроенный snippet работает не так, как jsfiddle?

Tags: поддержка, сниппеты, форматирование

Нашёл ответ, в котором вместо кода — ссылка на jsfiddle. Попытался перенести код в сам ответ, но не смог. Snippet показывает другой результат (вообще никакого текста нет). Пробовал открыть в FF и Chrome, результат одинаково неуспешный.

Что я делаю не так?

Ответ: [Как сделать блок резиновым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/155631/181472)

Источник: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/WTtQu/31/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

не подключен jQuery на странице сниппета, а в jsfiddle это скрыто в настройках

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JSFiddle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибку можно увидеть в консоли браузера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ага, нашёл где его подключить. Спасибо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я кстати заметил после обновления jsfiddle с этим проблемы стали, никто не знает где искать эти настройки :-D

Comment: А я как дурак все пытаюсь подключить их через `external resources` беря `url` библиотек из сниппета :-D и ненавидел фидл только по этой причине. Какое облегчение теперь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага, это вот самое частое решение которое я видел :-D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, там нет bootstrap! =\

Comment: @LEQADA, да, с этим они что-то пропустили, зато можно на кофескрипте и тайпскрипте писать :-) и не только css, но и scss