# Нужен автоматический импорт jsfiddle -> snippet

Tags: предложение, редактор, сниппеты

Нередко авторы вопросов и ответов предоставляют код в виде ссылки на jsfiddle. Приходится вручную открывать эту ссылку и редактор сниппета в разных окнах и перетаскивать код.

Было бы здорово сделать автоматический импорт, чтобы для вставки сниппета достаточно было дать ссылку на jsfiddle или любой аналогичный сервис. Примерно так, как мы сейчас вставляем картинки по ссылке. При этом должна происходить автоматическая [настройка зависимостей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2384/181472) (jQuery, angular и т.д.)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тогда и из plunkr тоже, в примерах для ангуляра часто требуется несколько файлов, а ни сниппет ни фиддл такого не позволяют, либо я не нашел

Comment: @Grundy это уже похоже на расширение существующего функционала сниппетов.

Comment: ага, и это было бы здорово. Но вроде менять редактор не планируют

Comment: @Grundy, несколько файлов всегда можно объединить в один. Если проблема не с require.js, конечно :) Чем меньше в примере файлов, тем лучше.

Comment: @Qwertiy, например загрузка шаблонов и json. У меня кстати шаблоны в сниппете по id не завелись что-то

Comment: Только [**пишут**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302282/5951529), что предпочтительнее, когда в сообщении присутствуют как сниппет, так и ссылка на JSFiddle.